# Compare variable with SQLite values

Tags: xcode, sqlite

I need to check if a variable has already been inserted on my SQLite db in order to change an image button, I tried to use this method but it's not working properly:

```
sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &Preferiti) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString *checkSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT * FROM ListaEventi WHERE idEvento=%@", [DettagliEvento objectAtIndex:7]];

    const char *insert_stmt = [checkSQL UTF8String];

    sqlite3_prepare_v2(Preferiti, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);

    if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
    {
        [_preferito setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"staroff.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        _preferito.tag=0;

    } else {
        [_preferito setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"staron.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        _preferito.tag=1;
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(Preferiti);
}
```

Is there any other way to write the statement to compare a variable with values inside my SQLite table?

Comment: You *must* check the return values of `sqlite3_prepare_v2` and ´sqlite3_step` for errors. What is the data type of `idEvento`?

Comment: If possible can you post me how the code should look like? idEvento it's an INTEGER type